# How to write to RAID 1 disks on Raspberry PI

Tags: filesystems, raid

I'm using Arch Linux on my Raspberry Pi, though I'm not sure that's relevant.  I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID#Setup) to set up a RAID 1 array with 2 USB HDs.  I then mounted the array (md0) in /media.  What I can't find is how to write to this array.  Do I write to /media/md0?  Or do I write to one of the disks and mdadm then copies it to the second?  md0 has only root write privileges.  When I wrote a test file to it, it creates the file like it would for a normal file system, but I don't see that file when I cd to the disks.  Shouldn't I be able to see the file on the disks?

Below is the output of mdstat, which is how the tutorial suggests to monitor the disks:

```
$awk '/^md/ {printf "%s: ", $1}; /blocks/ {print $NF}' </proc/mdstat
md0: [_U]
```

Comment: Your RAID array only has one device present...

Comment: Why don't you show us the whole `/proc/mdstat`? Is recovering, or is one drive missing? If you created a filesystem on /dev/dm0 and mounted that, you should be able to see files copied there, whether you `cd` to it or not. The write priviliges on `/media/md0` depend on the way you mount it. And don't write to the individual disks (or partitions), always write to the mounted filesystem on the raid.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  After @jasonwryan pointed out that `[_U]` meant only one drive was successfully added to the array, I repeated the process multiple times and it turns out that the second drive won't stay in the array after I add it.  It unmounts and then moves to a different file in /dev/ (for instance from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdc1)  @Anthon: I only wrote to `/media/md0`, but shouldn't I be able to see the file in all of the drives of the array at some point? (I'll update the question with the full `/proc/mdstat` output.)